# Calculator in HTML and JavaScript: sum rounding

Tags: html, sum, calculator

I am writing simple calculator in HTML. Why 2.2 + 2.2 = 4.4, BUT 10.2 + 2.2 = 12.3999999999 (not a 12.4)? I use Chrome.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to round the number, or want to know the reason of that behavior.

Comment: welcome to the club buddy

Comment: I would like to know the reason first. Also if I round result to 2 digits after dot it is still insane results as 4.4 and 12.39. Thanks!

Comment: How in the world are you impossibly writing this in HTML?

Comment: Same result in firefox,edge